# Bibtex and Google Scholar

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, pdftex, citing

I was wondering if someone could answer a question about the internals of bibtex.

I have a bibtex file that works well when the files are neat. For example

```
@article{HochwaldTC03,
author = "{B.M. Hochwald} and ten Brink, S.",
title = "{Achieving near-capacity on a multiple-antenna channel}",
journal = "IEEE Transactions on Communications",
...
}
```

works just fine. However, when I pull a bibtex citation from google scholar, it comes out like

```
@article{kenward2007multiple,
  title={Multiple imputation: current perspectives},
  author={Kenward, Michael G and Carpenter, James},
  journal={Statistical Methods in Medical Research},
  ...      
}
```

There are brackets alone (instead of brackets and quotes). When I add this to my bib file, bibtex (or latex, I'm not sure) freaks out and cannot read it. I was wondering why this is.

I feel that if google scholar is putting it out with just braces, it's probably correct. Can anyone tell me how to make bibtex work when it only has braces?

**Edit:**
I think it might be a bibtex compilation thing. I'll update soon.

It is in fact a bibtex thing. What I do is copy and paste the google scholar bibtex citations, and then compile bibtex twice, and then pdflatex 2 or 3 times and it works. But why is it like this?

It isn't an issue, the braces just make the word a unit that cannot be broken. My issue was with it not updating (which I attributed to braces), but the real problem was just with the order in which I ran bibtex and pdflatex.

Comment: It is braces or quotes. The inner braces in your first entry are protecting the name `B. M. Hochwald` from splitting up. Looking at the rest of the field, i would say there is something strange going on. The scholar entry looks clean and correct.

Comment: To the edit and the question therein: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852) The answer explains, why there is a special order in which you have to call the commands.